# Connecting to a ubuntu 14.04 VM-Guest from the Windows-VM-Host using putty if the Windows Host hast no network connection at all

Tags: 14.04

I want to connect my Ubuntu 14.04 VM with putty to the windows VM-host-machine. But the windows-hsot don't have any network connection (lan or wifi) .That's why ubuntu machine also not have any IP address.. So how can I connect it with putty??

How to configure my VM-Host / VM-Guest to use a local virtual network?

Comment: what virtualizing software do you use? try to configure the virtualizing software to use a host-only network and give the ubuntu-guest a virtual network card. you need to manually setup the ip-addresses.

Comment: I m using VMware workstation..  How can I give virtual network card to ubuntu guest system??

Comment: edit the settings from the virtual machine and add a network card in "host networking mode". Maybe you need to reinstall VMware workstation to enable this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install VMware workstation with the option "host networking" selected.

Than you need to configure the host and the client accordingly.

Read this [support article](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html) to understand and proper configure those options.

Comment: Thanks sir, I just change Bridget network to host in VMware settings and it's work fine.. Thanks..